# Vue.js Compnent doesnt show in Swal.fire html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sweetalert2

### This is my Swal.Fire in file1.js:

```
import TextModuleComponent from "../components/TextModuleComponent";
export default {
    components: {TextModuleComponent}
}

Swal.fire({

            title: 'Das Angebot per E-Mail versenden?',
            html:
                '<input class="swal2-input" placeholder="Empfänger E-Mail Adresse..." id="email" type="email" ></span>' +
                '<input class="swal2-input" id="header" placeholder="Betreff..." type="text"></span>' +
                '<div><TextModuleComponent ></TextModuleComponent><textarea class="swal2-textarea"></textarea></div>',
            showConfirmButton: true,
            showDenyButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Senden',
            denyButtonText: 'Nein',
            confirmButtonColor: '#2E8B57',
            icon: 'question',
            focusConfirm: false,
            preConfirm: () => ({
                email: $('#email').val(),
                header: $('#header').val()
            }),
```

### This is My TextModule Component:

[image]

### This is my Output:

[image]

---

### This is the Browser HTML output:

[image]

**There you can see, that the Textmodule Component is interpreted, but it doesnt show.**

But i dont know why my Sweetalert popup doesnt show "test". If i set "test" directly in swal html it works.

### EDIT

i tried:

```
 new Vue({

                 beforeCreate: ()  => {
                     Swal.fire({

                         title: 'Das Angebot per E-Mail versenden?',
                         html:
                             '<input class="swal2-input" placeholder="Empfänger E-Mail Adresse..." id="email" type="email" ></span>' +
                             '<input class="swal2-input" id="header" placeholder="Betreff..." type="text"></span>' +
                             '<div><text-module-component></text-module-component><textarea rows="10"  id="content" placeholder="E-Mail Inhalt..." class="swal2-textarea"></textarea></div>' +
                             '<div style="text-align:left"><i class="material-icons">description</i><label style="font-weight:bold;font-size:140%" class="label-on-left">Anhang</label></div>' +
                             '<div style="text-align:left"><label  style="font-size:110%" class="label-on-left">1 offer#' + object_id + '</label></div>' +
                             '<input class="swal2-file" multiple type="file" id=files>',


                     })
                 }
             })
```

### app.js :

```
 Vue.component('text-module-component', require('/resources/js/components/TextModuleComponent.vue').default);
```

**Error**:

```
unknown custom element: <textmodulecomponent> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

Comment: the problem here is `swal` is being called before `textmodule` component registration is completed, change so that swal gets call after textmodule get registered.

Comment: Ah okay thank you, do you know how to do it?

Comment: you can call `Swal.fire` in mounted method so it would be called after the component is registered and mounted.

Comment: you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48683390/using-vue-component-in-sweetalert2-content)

Comment: @Chandan look edit:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sweetalert popup is only rendering the HTML. It doesn't know anything about Vue components, so they are treated like HTML elements. You will have to initialize a Vue instance on the popup's HTML.

You should be able to get a reference to the popup body with `Swal.getHtmlContainer()` so after the popup is shown try something like

```
new Vue({
    el: Swal.getHtmlContainer()
})
```